# PHP debuging printing into command line

Tags: php, debugging, command-line, terminal

I have a php server, and I want to create a function that will receive a variable
and will print it into a terminal/command line that will be open at the same time.

Any idea how it can be done?
Linux based server or wamp, doesn't really matter

Comment: `function x($y) { exec($y); }`?

Comment: thanks for the fast reply!
however - not what i meant.
i don't want to run command line scripts from php,
but i want to be able to send that variable into "somewhere", and at same time, different command line will be open (like putty with ssh to the server) that will print that there

Comment: Do you want to write to a command-line console that's already open by some other process? What are the specs so PHP can identify such window? And I think OS does matter: Windows and Unix handle these things in entirely different ways.

Comment: not possible. that's not now the web works. you can't "keep windows open" because by design HTTP will CLOSE the connection when the request is done.

Comment: lets put it this way - i've seen it being done. so it is possible. but i don't know how, and i can't ask

Comment: it doesn't have to be to write to that console - maybe open a listener in the console, or keeps a file open that keeps being updated all the time.

Comment: If you want the browser to pop up a putty window on the CLIENT machine you will have add a customized protocol handler which opens putty with for example PUTTY://user@server

If you want the SERVER to open a connection to somewhere you can use @MarkB's first answer, exec can run any program on the server side.

Comment: @drizzt13 Well that's not a problem is it? just file_put_contents() APPEND and use a div on a javascript setInterval with to load the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the variable into a file and "tail" that file on terminal.

```
function writelog($msg)
{
    file_put_contents(FILE_PATH,$msg);  
}
```

You can also use error_log function instead of file_put_content. But i am not sure whether its an error message or not.

On terminal just run

```
tail -f FILE_PATH
```

P.S. FILE_PATH is absoulte path of the file where you want to write the data.

Answer (score 0):

printing to browser console is good ? 
Can use firebug and firephp with firefox http://www.sitepoint.com/debug-php-firebug-firephp/

Comment: i will check that - thanks!